# Videocard only working in safe mode

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-graphics-card, safe-mode

I am writing from safe-mode, because for some reason it does work in safe-mode (windows 7) though either black screens, or bluescreens on my normal windows mode, but I am extra sure, that the hardware itself has some error, and it is not software related, because the bios startup screen is also "teared" apart, and can't see anything of it.

My pc suddenly froze whilst watching a video, and after it, the above explained happened.

The card is an Nvidia 560TI if I remember correctly it is Gainward, but nevermind that.

My question is: Is there any way to start windows 7 by starting it in normal mode (starting every service) except use the videocard as it uses it in safe-mode, so I can at least save every data I have just to be sure, and use my pc that way as long as I don't have money for a replacement card :( (Tried 640x480 mode in normal windows boot mode, not working)

Thanks in advance, any answers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling the video driver and all NVIDIA related softwares while your in safe mode.
Then reboot windows normally and check.